# Will FusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates keep getting update even if application is minimized?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, fusedlocationproviderapi

I made single activity app that gets the current location of user and updates current location when user runs roughly 3 meter, i dont have idea how to save state of that application when minimized or destroyed to start things off where it was left and updates if everything changed during this, particularly im curious about requestupdate, will it keep getting updates about current location?

Answer (score 1):

In short no, your service can always be killed. Also Android O puts new limits on [Background Services](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html)

Comment: so what can we do to keep getting updates even if user locked the phone and if unlock or pick application from recent app it should have updated state

Comment: As it says in my link I posted, use a foreground service